# java, cast from A<T> to A<S extends T>

Tags: java, generics, casting

I am wondering how the following code work. I think it casts A< T> type to A < S extends T>, which shouldn't work, for example, you cannot case A< Number> to A< Integer>. But calling A.returnB() only causes warning: unchecked or unsafe operation.

```
class A<T>{
    public static <S extends Number> A<S>  returnB(){
    return (A<S>) B.INSTANCE;
    }
}

class B extends A<Number>{
    static final B INSTANCE = new B();
}
```

Comment: Yep.  Java will let you do this with a warning, and it may well result in a ClassCastException later.

Comment: guys, I know java will let me do that, but why? Never mind, I figured it out, it is item27 effective Java.

Comment: Because it _can_ be done safely in some cases, and there's no other way to do it, and Java implements generics with type erasure which makes that actually possible.

Comment: Do you mind to write a short answer so I can chose it as the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short of it is that Java implements generics with type erasure and allows you to fall back to raw types (pre-generics) for backwards compatibility, so unsafe casts *are* allowed.  They come with a warning, and may result in ClassCastExceptions at runtime, but they can also be legitimately used in some cases, so it's allowed.